# UITableView with different cell types and height

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I want to create a detail page which looks like the below image, here the text is coming from server.
Sometimes there will not be any About sections, TIMINGS sections
What is the best way to deal with such type of layouts
use `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` for this type of layouts.

Any one has idea please share it.

The View will look like the below link:
https://drive.google.com/a/i2india.in/file/d/0B7XzAO6OvWgHaDI4MGhrdXB1YTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I created custom cell in uicollectionview with storyboard with different cell identifier,based on json data i am populating the view but the cell is static how to make the cell increse the size depending on the text hight

Comment: Why are you using UICollectionView for a table view ?
Use a UITableView, and the method to set the height of each cell is tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
let me know if it isn’t clear

Comment: That google drive link only allows access to you. You need to put it somewhere public.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using UICollectionView for a table view ?
Use a UITableView, and the method to set the height of each cell is `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`
To calculate the height of the text use :

```
CGRect rect = [yourText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:fontText} context:nil];
```

where width is the width of your label/textview, yourText is the text you want the height of, and fontText is the font of the label/textview

rect.size.height will be the height of your text.

You can find another method of doing so here : http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

let me know if it isn’t clear